# Wolfram Cloud coding

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics

[image: this is the problem]
[image: am i doing it right?]

i want to prove that n is the same value to sin(0.9) which is the x, using taylor expansion, partial sum and finding N.

Comment: Am I doing it right?

Comment: Read the documentation for Sum here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html
and see that your line par[N_]:=Sum... which has a bright orange ! and an error message
telling exactly what is wrong below that do not match the documentation. As a test, try
summing x^y for y=1 to 4 and see if you get exactly the result you expect. Then you can try your actual sum. Probably best to do all this with a new fresh empty notebook to make certain that you don't have old incorrect values stored in the MMA cache.